# PHP Getting values from an array/random word generator/split string into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a sentence  that needs to randomly change parts that are in the curly braces. The important part is that the values inside the  braces can change (as in you could put any word in there), so

```
$x = '{Please,|Just|If you can,} make so, that this 

{incredible|cool|simple|important|useless} sentence {fast|correctly|instantly} 

changed randomly every time'; //this is the string that needs to be broken up
```

When I use

```
$parts = explode('{', $x);
```

it gives me an array that looks like this

> array ([0]=>[1]=>{Please,|Just|If you can,} make so, that this
>   [2]=>incredible|cool|simple|important|useless} sentence
>   [3]=>fast|correctly|instantly} changed randomly every time)

which doesn't work.

What I've done is:

```
 $parts = [

  ['Please,','Just','If you can,'], 

  ['incredible', 'cool','simple','important','useless'],

  ['fast','correctly','instantly'],

];

$p = [];

foreach ($parts as $key => $values) {

  $index = array_rand($values, 1);

  $p[$key] = $values[$index];
}


  $x_one = $p[0] . ' make it so that ' .  $p[1] . ' this sentence

changed ' . $p[2] . ' randomly every time.';

echo $x_one;
```

I have to get `$parts` from `$x`, because the words in the string `$x` can change. Don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback) to catch the sequence, split using `|` and return a random value:

```
$x = '{Please,|Just|If you can,} make so, that this

{incredible|cool|simple|important|useless} sentence {fast|correctly|instantly}

changed randomly every time';

// catch all strings that match with {...}
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\{([^}]+)\}~', function($matches){
    // split using |
    $pos = explode('|', $matches[1]);
    // return random element
    return $pos[array_rand($pos)];
}, $x);

echo $str;
```

Possible outputs:

- If you can, make so, that this cool sentence correctly changed randomly every time
- Please, make so, that this cool sentence fast changed randomly every time
- If you can, make so, that this incredible sentence fast changed randomly every time

Regular expression:

```
\{       # { character
 (       # capture group
 [^}]+   # all character until }
 )       # end capture group
\}       # } character
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never used   preg_replace_callback() before. And thank you for the explanation. I needed it

Answer (score 1):

Another approch can looks like this :

```
    $output = $input = '{Please,|Just|If you can,} make so, that this 

{incredible|cool|simple|important|useless} sentence {fast|correctly|instantly} 

changed randomly every time';


/**
 * Will output
 *  0 => string '{Please,|Just|If you can,}' (length=26)
 * 1 => string '{incredible|cool|simple|important|useless}' (length=42)
 * 2 => string '{fast|correctly|instantly}' (length=26)
 */
preg_match_all('/\{([^}]+)\}/',$input,$m);
foreach ($m[1] as $index => $rotateWord) {
    $words = explode('|',$rotateWord); //Split by pipe each words founds
    $randomWord = $words[rand(0, count($words) - 1)]; // Select random word.
    $output = str_replace($m[0][$index], $randomWord, $output);
}

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex can be extremely useful in these cases. It's used, for instance, in parsers to find the tokens.

In this case you want to get all substrings between curly braces.
This does the trick:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\{([^}]*)\}/', $x, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {Please,|Just|If you can,}
            [1] => {incredible|cool|simple|important|useless}
            [2] => {fast|correctly|instantly}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Please,|Just|If you can,
            [1] => incredible|cool|simple|important|useless
            [2] => fast|correctly|instantly
        )
)
```

The expression `'/\{([^}]*)\}/` means:

- `/`: this could be any character
- `\{`: start with start curly brace
- `([^}]+)`: everything that is not an end curly brace (the parentheses are used to isolate the matched expression, that's why the result is in the index number 1 of an array)
- `\}`: end with an end curly brace
- `/`: it must be the same as the first character

In other words: anything between curly braces.

You can test regular expressions at https://regex101.com/ or at https://regexr.com/.

But that's not enough: you want to replace those matches. `preg_replace` can do that, but it's also not enough, because you also need to call some function to select a random substring. `preg_replace_callback` can do that.

```
<?php

$x = '{Please,|Just|If you can,} make so, that this 

{incredible|cool|simple|important|useless} sentence {fast|correctly|instantly} 

changed randomly every time';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{([^\}]+)\}/',
    function ($matches) {
        $options = explode('|', $matches[1]);
        return $options[array_rand($options)];
    },
    $x
);
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the helpful information, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If the values inside the braces can change, it is, in fact, better to extract them from the template into arrays, as you have done in the question. Having parts array and template string, you then can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) alongside with [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr):

```
$parts = [
  '%part1%' => ['Please,','Just','If you can,'], 

  '%part2%' => ['incredible', 'cool','simple','important','useless'],

  '%part3%' => ['fast','correctly','instantly'],
];

$template = '%part1% make so, that this %part2% sentence %part3% changed randomly every time';

$result = strtr($template, array_map(function ($values) {
    return $values[array_rand($values, 1)];
}, $parts));
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/43d7ade11ed04e382ff5e1d3d93fb75b29b4d824).